# Hibernate calls save even after exception thrown

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-jdbc, spring-orm

I have below piece of code in my project. An exception is thrown at line # 4 still my product details are saved. I am having hard time to understand why does it save product details even after  throwing the exception

```
class Product{
@Transactional
    addDetails(){
        try{
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
           throw new Exception("Details dont match") //Line 4
        }
       productDAO.save(productDetails) 
       addAdditionalDetails(productDetails)
    }
   }

class ProductDAO {
   @Transactional
   public void save(Product productDetails){
       entitiyManager.merge(productDetails)
   }
}
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back): In its default configuration, the Spring Framework’s transaction infrastructure code only marks a transaction for rollback in the case of **runtime, unchecked** exceptions (emphasis mine).

Comment: Well, you're throwing a **checked** exception, and you expect your changes not to be saved. The changes will be saved, because Spring only rollbacks changes if you throw a **runtime, unchecked** exception.

Comment: No. A runtime exception is an exception that extends... RuntimeException. This is fundamental stuff: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/